# Problem in adding cmd-line tools to VS Code for flutter setup

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re4Y7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnRK5.png)

I am facing a problem in adding cmd-line tools to vs code for flutter setup. I set the path also to the environment variables but it didn't work.

Comment: You can download cmdline tools using Android Studio. Open Android Studio then go to Settings> Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android Sdk > Select SDK Tools Tab > Navigate to Android SDK Command-line tools(Latest) > Select first item i.e version 7 > Press Apply Button

Answer (score 0):

Hit cmd:

```
flutter config --android-sdk "path upto ~/flutter"
```

Make sure you have downloaded all necessary platform-tools and also place flutter sdk path to environment variables.
Restart the IDE and hope it works